# AWS API Gateway token test Response Code: 401

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, api-gateway

Thanks if anyone can help me. I am building a cognito user pool + API gateway solution in AWS. Now the configuration is done but the token is not working. Here is how I tested,

I used API endpoint

```
https://mydomain/login?response_type=token&client_id=5gjg8956um7bf2h5c3fuav1o46&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com
```

to get a token, here is the result.

```
https://www.example.com/#id_token=eyJraWQiOiJiTTcrSVlMUHBHVTBQK3FnTmkrMWxSeGFyNjRrb3hxYUluemptZllMTmZ3PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.lkTA49l_EQpWnhiLnKdbBR1anA0H4psFwEEBJuWgwQ6Iwg_GVZgvl3Sf0_p8OF-_vgRvcGbg1uI7nJdcTBs5EAcLV75AKfglQT7UjWXQtv10D7lh86sLNmIuLWRcJDV-8iCNSlHeFqJnBcskEH4yTXJI03s7Ikp9ZVZiNDW-wZzt6fW3n1SEtfN57sV4xvknByJBqswwUv07vL3URGk60MLMfLex16vVijBVHOhvMwWByEOpvWFMH3jY0NrGjx9ty5U4I-Bq1OvwJlR5SGPz2OjiPMdXnGM8eA-E8AUHjY8VtFIW4Ec6d74axlw7qMIayUHL8UaNMKKHSDM_giIpMg&access_token=eyJraWQiOiIxOEpWY2hGcWowQndhNjkxdUFlWW5IVThxdWdaWVhxOW9FaGFZNUd3cGtZPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.J0j9jZFzEG8gjowipZdJ_O_uXUKP5Jyk5PrZvWf5yVZ4jbdoJpgom3IcxFcaDvXbTkB_NNx9soq8Prc-whpYrjQ9RxDTd3Fb6ZyDOXhRaVQAmQSnagVr0_jPhH9Bw4_AS_4jNy4t27yDufpOnEgNWQW1sy96zpuaLFHJYAQblaJCxt_qbf_KETRDCil8ap63XUbAElaCvnSRrIGCcXmVOPChUMDSHVDu4CoMm9cgRQvj-kWFKP96YEO62tFa4_gZk1CICvjFEi7VCH0tvN9JVe8baSHm2GL1jaTeoUeE0jmGPGxGc-7fDBY37JjPbnPiHDZlm3D8eGE1AhO5qI3rng&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer
```

I verified the token on https://jwt.io/ and it is decodable. However, when trying to test the token in test tool in API gateway Authorizer, I got a 401 error.

Also, I tried to post the request in Postman as well and the result is also 401, with the following result.

```
{
"message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

My take is that if I can get a token through the endpoint, the token must be correct, right? How can I troubleshoot? thanks

Comment: Pass the token in the auth headers.

Answer (score 0):

Now I used the "wild rydes" app to sign in for a token, and the token will pass the Authorizer test in API gateway, also Postman API call is working.

Still, the token generated by "Hosted UI" in the Cognito does not work, as in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The Cognito authorizer on your API Gateway will accept either the ID token or Access token, depending if you specified an OAUTH scope to the API Gateway method when adding the authorization.

The Authorizer test on API Gateway will only accept the ID token. So I would suggest checking that you are getting a token from the correct Cognito UserPool that matches your API Gateway Cognito authorizer and then check your API Gateway method to see if you specified an OAUTH scope. If specified a scope, this scope will need to be in the Access token sent to API Gateway. If no scope specified, send the ID token.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the OAuth scope. In my description, the token I got is called "id_token", I assume it is an ID token, yet failed in the Authorizer test and actual API call. I will do some checking and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: The ID token should always pass the API Gateway authorizer test if it is the correct UserPool on the API Gateway authorizer. I would check that first :)

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem where a user's id_token is passing the Authorizer test in API Gateway, but when I use it in a `Authorization: id_token` header for a fetch it's returning `failed to fetch`. Did you ever find a solution to this?